# .net project integrated database

Tags: c#, .net, database

I am looking for a database management system which

1. Can be completely integrated into c# .net project and does not require an installation
2. Uses a little memory as possible
3. Search performance is good
4. Open source

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at SQLite

http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki

For further information look at the features :

http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/features.wiki

Comment: +1, is the best one, thread safe and really thin. Unfortunately the only drawback it is not working in medium trust

Comment: we tried sqlite, unfortunately it requires c++ 2005 redist installed :( so no go for us right now.

Answer (score 2):

I second Antonio Bakula's recommendation of SQLite and I advice you taking a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/ - an open-source library allowing you to access SQLite databases in a manner consistent with regular API of ADO .NET.

As for a real-size working example, I used it in that open-sourced project: http://morawski.codeplex.com/ (the overall code quality is so-so - I was starting in C# at the time - but SQLite access works all right).

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered SQL Server Compact, answers most of your demands.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact

Isn't open source, but is free and re-distributable.

Comment: How do I use it without installation?

Comment: It is just a file as far as Windows is concerned. Everything you need to access it should be in the .net installation already. No extra install.